# The article tag and the img

Tags: html, semantics, article

I understand that the article tag is "an independent item section of content"
www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/article

I have a page only with a blog post. That blog has an img and a caption on top of the text (it is an img that illustrates what I tell in the text of the blog). Should the img and caption be inside or outside the article tag?

The img:

```
<img src="1.png">
<div>Caption of the image</div>
```

The blog post simplified:

```
<article>
<h1>Title of the post</h1>
<div>Last Updated: 2016-01-07</div>
<div>       
    <p>This is the body of the post</p>
</div>
<p>Author of the post</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check both `figure` and `figcaption` tags.

example from the docs:

```
<figure>
  <img src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="An awesome picture">  
  <figcaption>Fig1. MDN Logo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And if the `figure` is related to the `article`, then I'd put it inside the `article` tag.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this already has an accepted answer, but I thought it could use a bit more info regarding your question:

> Should the img and caption be inside or outside the article tag?

In terms of semantic HTML, the image and caption content can be nested inside the `<article>` tag since the permitted content for `<article>` is [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), which both `<img>` and `<figure>` are defined as flow content.

The `<article>` element indicates self-contained content, meaning that if you removed all the other HTML except the `<article>` element, the content would still make sense to a reader. [Semantic Sectioning - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#Article_Element)

Have a look at the code snippet below for one valid way to markup a blog post with `<article>` and add a nested `<img>` or even better like @rafaelbiten suggested, a `<figure>`.

```html
<article>
  <h1>Title of the post</h1>
  <p>Author of the post</p>
  <p>Last Updated: 2016-01-07</p>
  <figure>
    <img src="1.png" alt="Some alt text">
    <figcaption>Caption of the image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p>This is the body of the post</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use img tag in article if the image is related to article.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).